# Bulk Delete in Azure Cosmos Db from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor to implement BulkDelete in Azure Cosmos DB. And I am using powershell script to call the bulkexecutor methods. But the BulkDelete method is returning null when the $idAndPartitionKeys is not empty. Below is the code I am writing to create the input for BulkDelete method.

```
$pkIdTuplesToDelete = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Tuple[string,string]]]::new()
Foreach($entry in $idAndPartitionKeys){
                    $tupleEntry = 
[System.Tuple]::Create($entry.partitionKey, $entry.id);
                    $pkIdTuplesToDelete.Add($tupleEntry);
                }
                $bulkDeleteResponse = $bulkExecutorObj.BulkDeleteAsync($pkIdTuplesToDelete).Result;
```

Comment: What do you mean by this?:

    the BulkDelete method is always returning null and the BulkDelete
    method is returning null when the $idAndPartitionKeys is not empty. If it's always returning null, it's always returning null.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I have edited the question

Comment: interested. but not enough code to be able to reproduce